# Inserting characters intro a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I need to insert a character into a string of letters that are in alphabetical order, and this character has to be placed where it belongs alphabetically.

For example I have the string `string myString("afgjz");` and the input code

```
cout << "Input your character" << endl;
char ch;
cin >> ch;
```

but how can I make it so that after inputting the char(say b) it is then added to the string on the proper position resulting in the string becoming "abfgjz".

Comment: Find the correct position and use [`std::string::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)

Comment: You could also use a `int` array of size 26. Then you can add a letter in O(1), by increasing the counter. Converting this array to a `string` costs then O(n) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class std::string has the following insert method (apart from other its insert methods):

```
iterator insert(const_iterator p, charT c);
```

So all what you need is to find the position where the new character has to be inserted. If the string has already the same character then there are two approaches: either the new character is inserted before the existent character in the string and in this case you should use standard algorithm `std::lower_bound` or the new character is inserted after the existent character in the string and in this case you should use standard algorithm `std::upper_bound`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how this can be done using standard algorithm `std::upper_bound`. You may substitute it for `std::lower_bound` if you like. Though in my opinion it is better to insert the new character after existent one because in some situation you can avoid moving characters after the target position that to insert the new character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string myString( "afgjz" );
    char c = 'b';

    myString.insert( std::upper_bound( myString.begin(), myString.end(), c ), c );

    std::cout << myString << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
abfgjz
```

Comment: Thanks for this Vlad from Moscow :D this worked like a charm, and here I was thinking I'd have to break it into arrays or something :D didn't think it would be this simple. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::lower_bound` to find the position to insert.

```
myString.insert(std::lower_bound(myString.begin(), myString.end(), ch), ch);
```

A more generic solution would be having a function like

```
namespace sorted
{
  template<class Container, class T>
  void insert(Container & object, T const & value)
  {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    object.insert(std::lower_bound(begin(object), 
      end(object), value), value);
  }
}
```

And then use

```
sorted::insert(myString, ch);
```